# What is this passive construction called?

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice, dependent-clause, adverbials

I wonder what *the tax raised* is called as a sentence part shown below, and whether it's grammatical. Please suggest corrections if it isn't.

> *The tax raised*, more small enterprises will close down.

Maybe it should be expanded to

> *Having the tax raised*, more small enterprises will close down.

It seems to me that it is an adverbial modifier of condition. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's an abbreviated form of

> *[With] the tax (having been) raised,*

It seems reasonable to call this an adverbial clause modifying *close down.*

Answer (score 2):

I would call it an ''absolute construction''. While it is grammatical here, it is semantically very odd, because it is normally used in (somewhat literary) narrative, for an event which preceded the action of the main clause, but did not specifically cause it.

A more conventional example would be

> Dinner eaten, we went out.

So *dinner eaten* means *when the dinner had been eaten*, but refers to a specific event in the narrative.

Here the writer seems to be trying to use it to mean *when the tax has been raised*, referring to a hypothetical event in the future, and furthermore an event which is likely to have a direct causative connection with the main clause. In both of these respects, the use of this construction is not usual here.

Comment: _That said,_ is another, similar construction, meaning 'with that having been said'.

Comment: Maybe it *is* being used in heightened prose. And if it was, *The heavy dinner eaten, they slept soundly on full stomachs for the first time in weeks...,* it could be ok and causal, no? (Not Nobel prize material, perhaps!)

Comment: Absolute phrases are often formed with present participles: _Her hair flowing in the wind, Ophelia raced to the river._  They can even be verbless: _Happy with his lolly, the small boy didn't see the seagull take the man's sandwich._ / _Exhausted, the man sat down to rest._

Comment: Probably from the [ablative absolute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_grammar#Ablative_absolute) in Latin.

Comment: Yes this is the English equivalent of the ablative absolute in Latin. For example, *"The carriage being full, I decided to walk."* which would be a literal translation from the corresponding Latin construction. Generally, though, when reading, you'd say "I decided to walk because the carriage was full." In other words, sounding awkward, the more literal and concise form can/should be expanded.

Comment: You say *dinner eaten, we went out* means *when the dinner had been eaten,...*. I would have thought it meant *dinner having been eaten,...*. There is a difference. Whilst yours implies that the going out immediately followed dinner, mine does not suggest immediacy of one event following the other.

Comment: @WS2: you may be right about the nuance. But your paraphrase is still an absolute expression: my concern was to render it as a (less literary) temporal clause with an explicit conjunction.

Answer (score -1):

I would say the author means "If the tax is raised, more small enterprises will close down" and it is a sloppy way of writing to say "The tax raised". The reader has to find out how it is meant.